# Procedure for updgrading Lotus Notes 8.5 to 9.0?

Tags: networking, lotus-notes

I need to upgrade my Lotus Notes 8.5 Server to 9.0. Which files do I need to backup? It is only the server that I need to upgrade. Also, if there is a tutorial on how to do the upgrade I would appreciate a link.

Comment: I don't know of a tutorial per se, but be sure to backup the encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some help documents:

- [Basics steps to upgrade the Domino server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21472991)
- [Upgrade Process and Steps for Moving to Domino / Notes 9.0](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Upgrade_Process_and_Steps_for_Moving_to_Domino_sla_Notes_9.0_)